# recv function for TCP socket in C++

Tags: c++, image, sockets, tcp, recv

I am new in socket programming. I have a  client application written in c++ that connect to camera. And then Camera sends the packet of frames in chunks between 0 - 1460. I have used recv function to receive the packet. I saw soo many question in which it was clearly mentionthat recv function return the bytes received, but in my case recv function returning the value written in the 3rd parameter of the recv function i.e len. So is their anyway through whichI can find the actual bytes received.

I even try to use char* but that not even work.

So, anyone please tell me the solution.Any help will be appreciable. Thank in Advance

```
char *buf = new char[1461];
int bytes = recv(sock, buf, 2000, 0);
printf("%d", bytes);
```

that always print 2000.
because of that after the valid bytes in the buf their are unknown bytes that's results in unexpected Image.

Comment: If the array you're telling `recv()` to read into isn't 2000 chars long, you shouldn't tell `recv()` that it is. That causes undefined behavior when it starts writing into memory outside of the bounds of the array you allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code has a bug (which leads to undefined behavior). 
You have allocated 1461 bytes but you are trying to read more than that:

It should go like this:

```
vector<char> buf(5000); // you are using C++ not C
int bytes = recv(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0);
std::cout << bytes;
```

Secondly result is as expected. Camera sends much more data than 2000 bytes, so I'm not surprised that number of bytes read covers whole requested size.

Comment: first of all thank you sir for your response, when I capture in wireshark I found that camear send data packets continuously  but in chunks between 100-1460 my recv function is working in while(1) loop

Comment: does't matter what chunks are send. System can merge them. Information about chunks size is not available and not needed. Never assume that if one party sends block of data in one size same size will be received on other side. Anything can happen with chunks between sender and receiver and you do not have control over that. They can be merged and can be chopped.

Comment: thank you sir one last question can I make vector of size 10000

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala yes, you can, std::vector or the "new" operator use the "heap" region of your program, so as long as you have memory in your computer, you don't have to worry about it. Plus, if you don't have enough memory, "new" or "std::vector" will throw an exception. 10 KBytes is a tiny memory space, so everything will be alright.